# Remove special symbol from the character

Tags: string, c#-4.0, char

i want to remove ` symbol from below string .  how can i do that?

For example :

string StateName = "Québec";
in the above string e character has special symbol, how can i remove special symbol from the string to make it as Quebec;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the ` symbol itself cannot be removed, you can use Replace method of the string to do this

```
string StateName = "Québec";
StateName = StateName.Replace('é','e');
```

That will do it